# Change activity background from code

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin.android, android-activity

I have an activity with a background:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="@drawable/background_fingerboard" />
```

How can I change background image from code? I actually use mono, but Java samples will also be helpful.

Comment: I choose @imran answer becouse it's most full.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

first add  LinearLayout id as in your layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutid" 
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="@drawable/background_fingerboard"
```

and in code part set background as::

```
LinearLayout  linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutid);
 linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_fingerboard);
```

Answer (score 3):

In java we do like this

Give id to LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id=@+id/parentLayout
```

Then in code

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  Or
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(d); Or
layout.setBackgroundResource(resid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout  vi = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(<id>)
vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.<id2>);
```

you need to provide the id to your LinearLayout  in XML as well....

Comment: No you don't. You can just manipulate the layout in code if you don't feel like making another XML like the answer by Vipul. That is great if you just need to change one or two fields.