# android setting layout background to iamgeview

Tags: android, layout, imageview

**I have a class that extends AsyncTask to get image from a URL:**

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

**I can load it to every ImageView I want, like that:**

```
new DownloadImageTask(mRecipeImage).execute(ImageURL);
```

I an getting the image while the app is running (dynamically).

**I want to set a Relative Layout's background to the image that I am getting from the web.**

any ideas?

Comment: Try to use AndroidQuery for Async image loading : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: You can see this question: [change activity background][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115158/change-activity-background-from-code

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this link:

[UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample)

may it is help full to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use an `ImageLoader` library like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) for downloading and setting Image.

code snippet for using [`picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load("ur_image_url").into(bmImage);
```

code snippet for using `Volley`

```
String url = "http://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png";

// Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null,
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            bmImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
        }
    });
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```