# Changing background image of an Android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to set a background image for my mainActivity according to a base-64 data record in a JSON file. I should convert that base-64 data into my background image, so drawable resource folder cannot help me. Any Suggestions?

**More Explanation:** I don't have an image in my drawable resources. My app reads a JSON file and parse it. One of JSON records is a base-64 data for the app background image. So after parsing, I want to decode this data and set it as my main activity's background.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20base64%20to%20image

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis At first I chose an id for my layout and then set a default background image (in the drawable folder) for it: RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout); rl.setBackground(R.drawable.game_1); Now I want to change this background with the one in my json file (base-64 data). Here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change activity background from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115158/change-activity-background-from-code)

Comment: @jankigadhiya Thanks for your link. but it's when you have an image in the drawable folder; but I have not any images. It's only a base-64 data that should be converted to the image and then it can be set as the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String base64String){
     try{
       byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(base64String,Base64.DEFAULT);
       Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
       return bitmap;
     }catch(Exception e){
       e.getMessage();
       return null;
     }
      }
```

Call this method by

```
String bas64String="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT.......=="

bas64String=bas64String.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
    Bitmap b=StringToBitMap(bas64String);
    if(b!=null)
    {
   Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(b);
  yourlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

Drawable backgroundDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```